# SQL replace all row values in view column by value from column of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL, so it might be an easy question, but I couldn't find the solution by myself.
I need to replace or update all values in a new column `Startdate` of a view (`view1`) by the values in column `Startdate` in a table (`table1`). The values in `table1` are always the same (it is a date, e.g. 01.01.2001 00:00:00).

What I've done so far is to create an empty column with the right format in the `view1`:

```
CREATE VIEW view1 
AS SELECT [fields], 
          [other fields], 
          cast(NULL as datetime2(7)) AS [Startdate] 
FROM ...
```

Now I've tried to update the column by:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[view1] 
   SET [dbo].[view1].[Startdate] = [EGDB].[dbo].[table1].[Startdate]
```

But I get the error "Update or insert of view or function 'view1' failed because it contains a derived or constant field."

Where is my fault?

Comment: As the error tells you, you *can't* `UPDATE` the value of `StartDate`, it's an derived value. You need to update the value in the underlying table(s).

Comment: But it should only be an empty column? That's why I've created it as ```cast(NULL as datetime2(7))```. Or is this, because it is view and can't be updated? Is there a way to simply join the column from the table to the view? But I'm missing a linking column (which would be no problem, as there is always the same value in every row of the table).

Comment: A `VIEW` isn't a table, it's a pseudo table defined by a `SELECT`. If you want the value of the column to change, you need to change the definition of the view itself.

Comment: What you want isn't just replacing `cast(NULL as datetime2(7)) AS [Startdate]` with `[table1].[Startdate]`  and in the `FROM` adding `CROSS JOIN [EGDB].[dbo].[table1]` in the view's definition? `CROSS JOIN` doesn't need a linking column, and I guess `[table1]` has only one row.

Comment: @ Dávid Laczkó: Unfortunately, ```table1``` has several rows and several columns, so using ```CROSS JOIN``` produces a very large view.... I've tried this and that's why I'm now looking for an alternative.

Comment: @ Larnu: thanks for your explanation. But I've read that it is not possible to create a view and ```SELECT``` from different tables, isn't it? So that I include the column from ```table1``` already when I create ```view1```?

Comment: *"But I've read that it is not possible to create a view and SELECT from different tables, isn't it?"* I don't know where you read that, but it's completely untrue. It's completely disproved by the first example in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-a-simple-create-view).

Comment: Thank you for the example, I had misunderstood something then - as I said, I've just started with SQL, so I appreciate every helpful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments and in the question 'the values in `table1` are always the same', you can
`CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP (1) [Startdate] FROM [EGDB].[dbo].[table1]) as startdate`,
and use `startdate.[Startdate]` instead of `cast(NULL as datetime2(7)) AS [Startdate]`.
However I consider it strange that all rows have the same value - if it wasn't the case or in the future it won't be, you can change `TOP (1)` to `MIN` or `MAX` to get the earliest/latest startdate, respectively.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. It is indeed always the same starting time (because it is extracted at a specific day at midnight), but it is helpful to know how to adapt it when needed.